# Building Error 32 bit .exe using cross compiler on 64 bit platform

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I was able to build 64 bit .exe using cross compiler path on 64 bit platform as below
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN \x86_amd64;

But when I tried to build 32 bit .exe using same path and on same 64 bit platform.
I am getting an error like below,

fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

I think it may be possible to build 32 bit .exe using 32 bit path as below
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN,
But if I try to build with 32 bit path I may get TrackFileAccess Error.

Can I know any solution how to build  32 bit .exe using cross compiler on 64 bit platform

Thanks&Regards,
Deva P

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're trying to link an x64 built lib into your x86 program.  Check your linker `Additional Library Directories` paths are set to the right location (i.e. 64 bit versions), and that any libraries you're building yourself have the right build configuration set.